# Number split from a string is not numeric

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
duration = inputScriptLine.split(' ', 1)[1]
if type(duration) == str:
    print '    Error: Sleep duration "' + duration + '" is not numeric'
```

given `SLEEP 50`, I get `Error: Sleep duration "50" is not numeric`

I am not too concerned as to why, I just want to know how I can code so that `SLEEP 50` is valid and `SLEEP APNOEA` is not.

Comment: Are you expecting only positive integer values?

Comment: @TimPietzcker That could probably be assumed - it's a sleep duration.

Comment: @Tim, "1.0",`"1.5"` are not positive integers but certainly not unreasonable possibilities,  I would consider both to  be "numeric"

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Fair point. I guess the OP needs to answer, as 1/2 of the answers assume it's integer.

Comment: @Tim, The OP uses `numeric` so taking that literally using isdigit would be the wrong approach, because something is not an integer would not mean it is not numeric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**isdigit()**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
if not duration.isdigit():
    print 'Error: Sleep duration "' + duration + '" is not numeric'
```

It would check whether all characters in `duration` are digits or not.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to accept more than just ints you should cast to float:

```
def is_numeric(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


duration = inputScriptLine.split(' ', 1)[1]
if not is_numeric(duration):
     print('    Error: Sleep duration {} is not numeric'.format())
```

`float("1.0")`, `float("1")`, `float("1.5")` etc..  would all return True but int("1.0"), `int("1.5")` etc..would also return False which if you are actually looking for numeric input would be wrong.

If you want to make sure you also get a positive number, store the result after you cast and return `f > 0`:

```
def is_positive_numeric(s):
    try:
        f = float(s)
        return f > 0
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
    duration = int(duration)
except:
    pass
```

This will attempt to convert it to an int, if it's not numeric it will fail and stay a string.

DeveloperXY's solution is cleaner, but if you want to use the value as an int later on, my solution is useful.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if the input is a string. It will be - you've just used the `split` command on a string.

You need to check if the string contains only numeric characters, with `.isdigit()`.

Note that this won't accept negative inputs, but you don't want those as this is a time.

So your new code is:

```
duration = inputScriptLine.split(' ', 1)[1]
if not duration.isdigit():
    print 'Error: Sleep duration "' + duration + '" is not numeric'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
duration = inputScriptLine.split(' ', 1)[1]
try:
    duration = int(duration)
except ValueError:
    print '    Error: Sleep duration "' + duration + '" is not numeric'
```